# My custom MSI will not install on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, windows-server-2008, setup-deployment

I have several deployment projects with some of them being web deployment projects.  My MSIs have successfully installed on both Vista and Windows Server 2008.  They will not install on Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2 unless I run it from a console window that I right clicked to "Run as administrator"  Unless I do this, none of my installers will successfully install.

I cannot force my customers to have to open up a console window as I have to install the software.  As a workaround for now, our customers are doing this but I will need to fix this in future releases.

I even tried creating a Launch Condition and setting the condition to AdminUser but that didn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "none of my installers will successfully install" So what happens? Do you get an error message? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: My Web Deployment MSIs say, "You do not have sufficient privileges to complete this installation for all users of the machine.  Log on as administrator and then retry this installation"

Comment: My other installers say, "Error 1001.  Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\xxxx\CustomAction.InstallState' is denied"

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to User Access Control (UAC) default settings. For detailed steps of the workaround read this post: http://rambletech.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/windows-server-2008-you-do-not-have-sufficient-privileges-to-complete-this-installation-for-all-users-of-the-machine/

HTH,

Ozzie.